# how to deal with this error npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! syscall open npm ERR! path C:\Users\M.Tech/package.json npm ERR! errno -4058

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, enoent

all i am traying to do is to run a react js or a react server but each time this error shows up

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\M.Tech/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\M.Tech\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\M.Tech\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-27T01_45_02_836Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\M.Tech\Desktop\admasell-buy>
```

Comment: note i have tried delating node mudoles and the package lock.jason

Comment: Well, does the `C:\Users\M.Tech\package.json` file actually exist? Does it contain what you expect it to contain?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: thank you all for helping i finally maneged to find and answer